# React throwing error code when trying to install d3 version

Tags: reactjs, github, d3.js

So I've got a forked project I'm attempting to reference in my React code. I've noticed the package has a different version of d3 then my own (it uses 5.5.0, mine uses 6.6.2). Whenever I try and do `npm install d3@5.5.0`
I get these errors thrown

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/<username>/react-d3-graph.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I've created a .env file holding. I've got it

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
REACT_APP_React=SHA256:/<code>
```

I've deleted node_modules and package-lock.json.
And I confirmed the code is the same as my SSH on GitHub, title and all. I'm not really sure why this is happening.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "d3": "^6.6.2",
    "d3-selection": "^2.0.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.0.0-alpha-5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
    "react-request": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.2",
    "react-scroll-wheel-handler": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "use-neo4j": "^0.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "write-json-file": "^4.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9",
    "xtypejs": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "api": "npx json-server --watch .\\src\\components\\limit.json --port 8000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "d3-drag": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-force": "^2.1.1",
    "d3-zoom": "^2.0.0",
    "react-d3-graph": "<git_username>/react-d3-graph",
    "react-router-scroll": "^0.4.4",
    "react-use": "^17.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to run it or how to include it in a separate project?

Comment: How I would implement it so I can still call the functions, but also the functions I implemented and exported. So for example, if I changed a function to do a+b instead of b+c, it would call my function doing a+b. But how to include it in the current project as well

Comment: The code files on that project appear to `export` their components like any other JavaScript application would.  Can you just put your forked version in a folder in your project and `import` what you need from it?  Or do you necessarily need to build this project separately and include its build output in `node_modules` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `package.json` to point to your forked github repo instead of the version number of react-d3-graph. Replace:

```
  "react-d3-graph": "x.y.z"
```

with

```
  "react-d3-graph": "your_github_username/react-d3-graph"
```

Then run `npm install`.

From then on, it will use your version rather than the original.

PS: note that [npm's support for github dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls) is far from perfect. I still run into some issues with it every once in a while. Obviously, you will also need to re-run `npm install` any time you make changes to the repo. But that said, it works.

Comment: This will force you to push to GitHub every time you want to make a change and use your fork.  There are alternatives like using `npm link` or just putting the project in node_modules.

Comment: Yes, for sure. But `npm link` isn't such a smooth experience either. Especially when collaborating with others, during deployment, and when publishing packages. It adds a lot of complexity and pitfalls in those situations.

Comment: So I've changed the info in my package.json to my fork, but whenever I change something and do npm install it says "up to date"

Comment: Also, with githubs new update adding access keys, does that not effect my ability to read? Because I just tried re-installing "react-d3-graph" after changing my package and it says ```npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Comment: This will only work with public forks, of course, but for those, of course, there are no permissions required. npm uses the https protocol internally. I don't think the publickey error you saw was thrown by what I proposed.

Comment: You were right, that error wasn't thrown from your command. However, I am getting ```Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-d3-graph' in ``` after swapping and doing npm install, then running npm start